# Output sonarqube result to different server locations

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, parameterized

Is there a way to output SonarQube results to 2 different server locations through a Jenkins configuration, using a single Jenkins build for each SonarQube output?

I know Jenkins has a concept of parameterized build where the build could be parameterized by the Sonar Server name.

Comment: How are you executing sonar analysis/scan? Using Jenkins' SonarQube plugin or through sonar-scanner as a client?

Comment: Using sonar-scanner as a client @saurabh14292

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you are talking about the parameterized plugin:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin

This plugin let you provide data when you trigger the build. This is a great plugin when your builds trigger each others, and you need data from a previous build executed on another slave.

If you want a single build, and the Sonar Server Name is determined inside the build, you will need to find your way using Shell.

Get it at some point:

```
SONAR_NAME=$( .... )
```

and re-use it within the same build:

```
ssh $SONAR_NAME@....
```

Comment: Tried to implement this solution, but I couldn't succeed.                        Currently I have a Jenkins job which uses the Sonar plugin to scan and push to a local Sonar server. 

I have added the configuration of the enterprise server and can swap the local server for the enterprise server. 

What I want to do is think of the best way to push the same build result to both servers.